# SQL DB2 LUW V9.7 Join to Nearest Date within range

Tags: sql, join, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to join to the nearest date with 2 tables (from PEOPLE to INJURIES), but only if there is a record within the past month.

Sample tables/outputs:

```
PEOPLE

Name          Date
John Smith    01/01/2016
Jerry Doe     01/14/2016
Jane Ellis    02/21/2016
Adam Patel    03/21/2016


INJURIES

Injury        Date
Broken Hand   12/30/2015
Broken Wrist  12/31/2015
Head Pain     01/13/2016
Broken Hand   02/02/2016


OUTPUT1 (Able to achieve, but not desired)

Name          Injury
John Smith    Broken Hand
John Smith    Broken Wrist
Jerry Doe     Broken Hand
Jerry Doe     Broken Wrist
Jerry Doe     Head Pain
Jane Ellis    Broken Hand
Adam Patel    {null}

OUTPUT2 (Desired Output)

Name          Injury
John Smith    Broken Wrist
Jerry Doe     Head Pain
Jane Ellis    Broken Hand
Adam Patel    {null}
```

Is there a way I can do the join without getting output1 in any step of the process? I am dealing with a significant number of records and would like to do this join with as little computational power as possible.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  (Having a hard time imagining any kind of real application that would try to assign injuries to people based only on dates).

Comment: No it is not, what I'm trying to do is tie prescriptions to the last diagnosis that a pain provider gave. Unfortunately, the information for prescriptions and visits to the doctor are in two separate tables.

Comment: It might be two tables but they should have a common key - the date could not be a useful key to do that - it might be a component but not the key

Comment: Unfortunately looking at the data, I could not find a common key between these two tables since medical claims are processed separately from prescriptions in my case. The only common key between the tables is a number used to identify members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is a bad design, this query will return the results that you want:

```
select
    p.name,
    (select injury
       from injuries x
      where x.date between p.date - 1 month and p.date
      order by x.date desc
      fetch first 1 row only)
from 
    people p;
```

You'd need to provide some additional details for performance reasons, but chances are that you'd want to have an index on `INJURIES.DATE` (preferably in descending order).

I'd recommend that you look for proper keys for joining the tables as using date alone seems like a good way to get incorrect data.

Comment: Thank you for this Ian, this was the answer that I was looking for. I realize the consequences of lack of a proper key, but this solution makes the best out of my current situation with the data I do have.